# Tera Wurfl for Drupal

Tags: 7, theming, mobile-tools

Has anybody added or know how to add tera wurfl to their drupal 7 site? I have tried to implement it on my test site with no success. For those of you who don't know, it is a mobile detection program. I'm also open to a good alternative. Doesn't seem like there is too much info on this topic in the forum. Any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) underwent [licensing changes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WURFL#License_update) a little while back, and I stopped using it.

I either use [Mobile Tools](http://drupal.org/project/mobile_tools) if I need all of the features it provides (mainly [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/mobile_tools) integration) or I use [get_browser](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) directly (make sure you have a recent [browscap.ini](http://browsers.garykeith.com/downloads.asp)).

I don't think Mobile Tools has a stable Drupal 7 release, though.

There is also the Drupal [Browscap](http://drupal.org/project/browscap) module, which purports to be better than the native version, though, I just manually keep my browscap.ini up-to-date.